# Code after ExcelWriter definition not being run

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to collect data from multiple excel files into separate sheets in a single workbook through Pandas. However, the code block after my ExcelWriter definition is never executed, and no error is thrown.

```
res_path = os.path.join(output_path, 'overview.xls')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(res_path)
# No statements from here onwards execute
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(output_path):
    for f in files:
        name = re.compile(r'(.*)_.*_(?:result.xls)').match(f).group(1)
        pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, f)).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
writer.save()
```

I have attempted to run various print statements (before the for loop, inside the for loop, after the save), but none of them are executed. I have also attempted to use ExcelWriter within a context manager, but the same problem occurs. I have attempted to wait for upwards of 5 minutes, with no avail. The file size is small (8kb) so I do not believe it would have taken longer than that to save.

I have also attempted to use a simple path (i.e just 'overview.xls') as an argument for ExcelWriter, which also doesn't work, leading me to believe that the path is not the issue.

Other engines (saving as .xlsx via XlsxWriter) also do not work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: I have also attempted to run this code on a Linux machine (I was previously on a Windows machine), but it has not changed anything; the code still freezes after `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(res_path)`, and any print statements after that or otherwise are never executed.

Comment: `print(type(os.walk(output_path)))`. My best guess it that it returns `None` and that will print as a blank line, unless you call `type()` which will give `NoneType`

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced that is the case; the code should not return None and you should get an error in that instance. It's not true that the code doesn't execute, but something is stopping the iteration; or something is missing from your question.

Comment: I have tried the os.walk independently, and it gets the files fine; I'm also unconvinced that it's an iteration problem as a print statement before the os.walk loop doesn't print, either.